# Can I use WordPress cool video extension to show screencast videos?

Tags: wordpress

I want to use cool video extension for displaying multiple videos on a page. But it takes videos only from youtube and uploaded videos.

If I want ot use videos from [www.screencast.com](http://www.screencast.com), is there any way to do this.

or please suggest any other extension which supports videos from www.screencast.com and display them in popup form.

Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Go for HTML5 Video Players, there are lot of players which support streaming video from another site. All you need to do is, just Install the pluggin and call the player and give the video URL. HTML5 Audio video players are the latest trend and easy to use with lot of Features. Go for it.

Comment: I believe that IE7 and IE8 doesn't support HTML5. You can check if your browser supports HTML5 video or not. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp